# Network traffic monitoring using RaspberryPi

Tags: internet, raspberry-pi, network-monitoring

The ISP in my country limit the internet with monthly quota 100GB 200GB and so on, so i must be careful of consuming all of it before the month ends so i decided to watch my home network traffic using RaspberryPi Model 3 B+ with KaliLinux installed on it to know every GigaByte i have consumed. (I have multiple devices in my home)

I have tried to use `vnstate` and `iftop` but it all show only the RaspberryPi traffic, Is there any way to know all the connected devices usage? Or is there anyway to know every GB that consumed by the devices?

Comment: Aren't all the devices connected to a central router? Most routers have an option for logging data traffic. You could write a simple script to extract that on a regular schedule and monitor that.

Comment: @jdh Unfortunately my TP-Link router doesn't support this feature.

Comment: The TP-Link firmware can be updated with logging with the OpenWrt software.  Here's the link https://openwrt.org/   The list of supported routers is here:  https://openwrt.org/toh/views/toh_fwdownload

Comment: I know but they doesn't support my Archer VR600